# Can magical traps be disabled using thieves' tools or other means?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic, equipment, traps

I'm wondering how one would disable magical traps.

The spell *[Find Traps](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-traps)* describes that it could find *[Alarm](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/alarm)* and *[Glyph of Warding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/glyph-of-warding)*, which to me makes them traps.

But a *Glyph of Warding* can just be a symbol placed on a surface.
Can this trap even be disarmed by hand?

Would it make sense to still allow the bonuses of thieves' tools to apply when trying to disarm it, or is there some other item or skill (such as Arcana) that would apply?

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin adding link the the DDB description of glyph is not a high priority task. We've already got one meta-approved retagging task pushing things to the front page each day, there is really no reason to be bumping several questions about glyph of warding to the front page at the same time. Please at least discuss these things in chat before you go about filling up the front page like this.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov, I'm done for today anyways, made 5 of them.

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin I'm showing 8 today, but maybe that's a bit nit picky. I (and I'm sure others) would really prefer projects like this get the blessing of a few other users before they are carried out. As you come across questions through your normal browsing that need updates, update them. But searching out questions to add DDB links for a single spell is not a task worth bumping several related questions to the front page.

Comment: Yes, I think I did three this morning too

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Would it make sense to still allow the bonuses of Thieves' tools when trying to disarm it or is there some other item or skill (such as Arcana) that would apply?

Those two cases are not mutually exclusive.

---

Let's address the skill first, because that's an easy one.

> Any character can attempt an Intelligence (Arcana) check to detect or disarm a magic trap, in addition to any other checks noted in the trap's description.

— DMG P 121

So, yes, they can use a different skill.

---

> Would it make sense to still allow the bonuses of Thieves' tools when trying to disarm it

I'm going to address this from two different angles. First *as a game rule* (i.e. what do the rules, as written, say):

> Proficiency with these tools lets you add your proficiency bonus to any ability checks you make to disarm traps or open locks.

— PHB p154

So RAW says "yes".

… but a player who trying to claim a bonus for simply having them would have me calling *shenanigans*. It doesn't make much obvious sense from a fiction-first perspective.

I'd ask the player to describe how they were using the tools to help them before allowing the bonus. They'd be welcome to invent whatever details they liked, just so long as they justified it.

*OK, so, I take a deep breath and spend a moment steadying my nerves. I don't want to have wavering hands for this. I take the copper wire in my pliers and carefully touch one end to the axial manna node and the other to the detection symbol — making sure not to put my hands over the glyph — that should short out the arcana potential and dispel it.*

Of course, if they came up with a sufficiently good explanation, I might go past giving them proficiency and skip the die roll entirely:

> In most cases, a trap's description is clear enough that you can adjudicate whether a character's actions locate or foil the trap. As with many situations, you shouldn't allow die rolling to override clever play and good planning.

— DMG p121

Comment: Why does the player need to provide an in-game justification for some actions that RAW clearly allows, but not for others? Why does the use of thieves' tools require the player to come up with magic technobabble to disarm a trap while use of the arcana skill doesn't?

Comment: @minnmass — From the answer "So **RAW says "yes"**. … but a player who trying to claim a bonus for simply having them would have me calling shenanigans. It **doesn't make much obvious sense from a fiction-first perspective**."

Comment: If the rules say thieves' tools can be used to disarm magical traps, why does the player need to jump through additional hoops to use them to do what the rules let them do? Do players also need to explain how they're disarming a mundane trap with thieves' tools? ... or how their having a healer's kit allows them to stabilize someone? It doesn't make much obvious sense from a fiction-first perspective how someone without training can throw "bandages, salves, and splints" at someone who took a fireball to the face and make them not be dying anymore in 6 seconds, but the rules clearly allow it.

Comment: This isn’t a discussion forum. I’m not going to debate the relative merits of a purely mechanical application of the RAW vs engaging with the fiction. I’m not going go off on tangents about how I would rule on other hypothetical situations (especially when they hit areas like “what do hit points actually represent?”). **This answer covers both the rules as written and the ruling that 2017-me would have given. Take what you want from it.** I’m not going to break into your house and complain if you follow the RAW.